# OpenCV-python not importing

Tags: python, android, opencv, pip, pydroid

I am using Pydroid to code in android. Though it is an ARM machine so I downloaded OpenCV-python wheel from [PiWheels](https://www.piwheels.org/) and successfully installed it using pip. But i can't import OpenCV anyways. Please help.

Here is what I tried:

```bash
/storage/emulated/0 $ pip list
Package             Version
------------------- -----------
android             1.0
appdirs             1.4.3
astroid             2.2.5
audiostream         0.2
certifi             2019.11.28
chardet             3.0.4
cPython             0.0.5
cycler              0.10.0
Cython              0.29.13
distlib             0.3.0
filelock            3.0.12
h5py                2.9.0
idna                2.9
importlib-metadata  1.5.0
isort               4.3.15
jedi                0.13.2
Keras               2.3.1
Keras-Applications  1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing 1.1.0
Kivy                1.11.0.dev0
kiwisolver          1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy   1.3.1
matplotlib          3.1.1
mccabe              0.6.1
numpy               1.16.2
opencv-python       4.1.1.26
pandas              0.25.1
parso               0.3.4
pip                 19.0.3
pygame-sdl2         2.1.0
pyjnius             1.1.5.dev0
pylint              2.3.1
pymongo             3.10.1
pyparsing           2.4.6
PySDL2              0.9.4
python-dateutil     2.8.1
pytz                2019.3
PyYAML              5.3
requests            2.23.0
scikit-learn        0.20.2
scipy               1.3.1
setuptools          40.8.0
six                 1.12.0
typed-ast           1.3.1
urllib3             1.25.8
virtualenv          20.0.10
virtualenv-tools    1.0
wheel               0.34.2
wrapt               1.11.1
zipp                3.1.0
```

```bash
/storage/emulated/0 $ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2019, 14:25:26)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module     named 'cv2.cv2'
>>>
>>> import opencv-python
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import opencv-python
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'
>>>
>>> import opencv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencv'
>>>
```

Comment: Can you more clearly separate the attempted imports and corresponding error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the module is cv2.

Try `import cv2` .

When I faced a similar problem in my laptop, installing opencv in a Conda environment did the job for me. Try removing opencv and try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows command line try to install: `pip install opencv-python`

Then `import cv2`.

Comment: this is an android problem, not Windows. besides, OP did manage to install `opencv-python` but the import failed in an android-specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Open cv library is declared for only premium users of pydroid so I guess that's the reason ......

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).